# Wordpress showing up on the wrong cPanel account

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel

On cPanel I have 2 accounts - and I can load them into a browser like with the following URLS (the IP address is made up):

```
https://11.22.33.44/~staticSite
https://11.22.33.44/~wordpressSite
```

The `~staticSite` is just a collection of .php files with no database.  One of these files (for example) is `index.php`.

The `~wordpressSite` is a standard WordPress site (Version 5.2.4).

The problem is that whenever I load `~staticSite` I get the theme from the `~wordpressSite` loaded with a 404/`Oops! That page can’t be found.` message.

Even if I try and directly load `https://11.22.33.44/~staticSite/index.php` the `index.php` is dropped and I end up seeing the 404 page as if I am on the `~wordpressSite` - however the address in the URL still reads `https://11.22.33.44/~staticSite/`

To try and combat this, I have completely terminated the `~staticSite` account through cPanel.  Then I recreated it (with the same name, just a different set of passwords/FTP details) and then re-uploaded the files to this new `~staticSite` - but the problem still persists - it is as if the `~wordpressSite` is leaking onto a completely different account.

There is no domain or DNS pointed to the `~staticSite` account yet.  However the `~wordpressSite` has a domain pointed to it and an SSL certificate set up for it.

The `.htaccess` file on the `~staticSite` reads as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

# The following redirects .co.uk to .com
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?staticsite\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.staticsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# The following forces a redirect to HTTPS instead of HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Is this issue caused by a combination of SSL certificates and the contents of this `.htaccess` file?  I am not sure if it is, and to check I have just deleted the `.htaccess` file altogether and the problem still persists.

Can anyone help?  I hope I have provided enough information - please ask if I have not.

Comment: Can you get to the static site by using `http://`?  cPanel will forward SSL traffic to the next site with a valid SSL that it can find.

Comment: Also, if you deleted the `.htaccess`, use a different browser or an incognito window - I seem to remember that that redirect gets cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the conversation I remember reading from a couple years ago:

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/https-site-name-here-redirects-to-a-different-site.395002/

From the link:

"If the account is assigned a shared IP address, and a SSL certificate is installed on that IP address, then any secure request to a domain name on that IP address will load the contents of the domain name the certificate is installed for. **This is by design.** [emphasis mine] You will need to assign a dedicated IP address to the account that uses the SSL certificate if you don't want that certificate applied to the other domain names on it's IP address."